# HTML Jquery.ajax post HTML document content to another page

Tags: html, jquery

I am building a self serve email campaign app for a client. I would like the client to download the template they desire and the data will be sent to another page.

I am using the `Jquery.Ajax` to post the data, though I need it to select the content of the html template the client chooses:

Get template

```
function getTemplate(id){
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ay/templates/Postcard_Template.html,
    data: 'EmailTemplate_id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
     $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#popupContact').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#content').html(data);
}

});
```

Post to new page...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: 'wwww.Test.co.uk/test.html,
    data: 'EmailTemplate_id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#popupContact').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#content').html(data);


});
```

I will then bind this to a form, any suggestions if this looks correct?

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can see wrong is a single quote missing at gettemplate:

```
function getTemplate(id){
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ay/templates/Postcard_Template.html',
    data: 'EmailTemplate_id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
     $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#popupContact').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#content').html(data);
}

});
```

and a single quote + bracket at post template:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: 'wwww.Test.co.uk/test.html',
    data: 'EmailTemplate_id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#popupContact').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#content').html(data);
    }

});
```

My suggestion if u are gonna bind this to a form u should serialize the form and pass it to the data parameter.
Short example:

```
<form id="menu">
    <select name="daymenu" size="3" multiple>

            <option value="1">maple</option>

            <option value="2">hickory</option>

            <option value="3">birch</option>

    </select>
</form>
```

then adjust your ajax data:

```
data: $("#menu").serialize(),
```

Good luck Tom :)

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your suggestion, I was thinking the same..-Yes, I have a number of templates, so would dynamically need to pass in the unique value-I was thinking of setting up a url location for each option then binding this in the 'get' Url: part instead of the hardcoded location, as its just not going to work.

Comment: Don't use `data: 'EmailTemplate_id=' + id,`, use `data: { EmailTemplate_id: id },`. jQuery will then do proper URL-encoding of of the parameters.

Comment: $("select#test").val() -> give this to the url parameter and give the select the id 'test' and your suggestion would work viva

Comment: Thanks for the guidance-I will hack away at this, looks the right approach.